# How can I make a Clickable Button in my Activity from the Navigation drawer?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener, android-view

I am working on an application that has a navigation drawer for displaying themes in my Activity.

The navigation drawer is spread out over several different layouts.

My goal is to make an OnClickListener for a button I placed in the nav_header_manage_rec.xml layout. If your familiar with boiler plate android, Its this area...

[image]

The green area at the top of the nav drawer is where I would like to add the button. I have tried to make a button using

```
 val themeDarkButton: ImageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.theme_dark_button)
```

in the activity that the nav drawer rests in, with no avail. Here's the hitch, the area where I want to add the button is in its own layout called nav_header that is set up just like a standard xml file.

there has gotta be a way to do this!

```
 themeDarkButton.setOnClickListener {


            val themeDarkText = themeSelectorView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.theme_dark_text)

            themeDarkText.text = "It works fine."

            Log.d("TESTING", "It is working fine.")

        }
```

**Goal:** When I swipe left and tap that little android head, an onclicklistener in the activity thats underneath drawer should respond and do something.

**Important** I do not want to select an item from the item menu. I know how to do that. I want to put a button in the green area, and then be able to click it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to run the button in the top menu
Maybe this will help you

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.itme1 -> {/*itme1 is your button*/
            webframe.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aradev.net")/*her my button make webview go tu url*/
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: No, sorry. That's exclusively for menu items. I just want to add a button above the menu items.